# Mousetrap key bindings updating $scope but not detected by $watch.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, mousetrap

Basically I have created a function to update a scope variable

```
// controller.js

$scope.variable = 0;
$scope.$watch('variable', function(){
  console.log("change from watch");
});

$scope.increment = function(){
  $scope.variable++;
  console.log($scope.variable)
}
```

When I bind a key to this function,

```
Mousetrap.bind('j', $scope.increment)
```

the console.log in the browser shows that the variable is incremented when the key, in this case "j", is being pressed, but the $scope.$watch function above is never called and the console.log message "change from watch" is not fired.

When I attach a click handler, however, on the html file,

```
// index.html
<a ng-click="increment()">{{ variable }}</a>
```

The variable increases, the console.log shows that the `$scope.variable` is incremented and the $watch function is being fired as well.

In addition to this problem, `{{ variable }}` does not change when I use the key binding, yet it changes when I click on it.

My guess is that there is something lacking in Mousetrap that causes the function to fire but not in sync with AngularJS $scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you read about [Databinding in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding). Basically, in order for AngularJS to react to changes, something needs to trigger a [$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest). The built-in `ngClick` directive does that under the hood.

When using non-AngularJS APIs (such as `Mousetrap`), you need to manually wrap the callback in [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply), e.g.:

```
Mousetrap.bind('j', () => $scope.$apply($scope.increment));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is exactly what I needed to know. And thanks for linking the page and giving the extra information, really helpful in continuing to understand AngularJS